# Why is there a limit of 10 in the -q argument of traceroute?

Tags: traceroute

The -q argument of traceroute sets the number of probes to be used.

On Linux systems it seems that this can only be up to 10. If a higher value is used traceroute returns.

> no more than 10 probes per hop

On a solaris box the same parameter is available and there it accepts more than 10.

I wonder why that limit is there. Is that just arbitrary choice?

Comment: So the question that needs answering: do you ever need more than 10?

Comment: I have specifically encountered a scenario on Solaris boxes where UDP probes from traceroute are consistently being lost or dropped at the 11th probe. I was therefore keen to investigate whether this behaviour would continue if I used a box with a different OS. It now seems I cannot pursue it using a Linux box--else I would have to mess with code and try to recompile traceroute.

Answer (score 0):

You can not expect that any program on any system generates identical outputs. Everyone is free to adapt the source code.

[POSIX](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) defines the application programming interface (API), along with command line shells and utility interfaces, for software compatibility with variants of Unix and other operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply defined in the source code of the tool, among other limits:

```
#define MAX_HOPS    255
#define MAX_PROBES  10
#define MAX_GATEWAYS_4  8
#define MAX_GATEWAYS_6  127
#define DEF_HOPS    30
#define DEF_SIM_PROBES  16  /*  including several hops   */
#define DEF_NUM_PROBES  3
#define DEF_WAIT_SECS   5.0
#define DEF_SEND_SECS   0
#define DEF_DATA_LEN    40  /*  all but IP header...  */
#define MAX_PACKET_LEN  65000
```

There isn't a comment indicating why, so I guess, "arbitrary choice" is it.

Probably the developers thought that more than 10 per hop would not be useful and would probably not represent a sane choice.

Are you dealing with high packet loss or jitter?  Even 10 packets should be more than enough to establish whether there is high packet loss or jitter.

Comment: I have specifically encountered a scenario on Solaris boxes where UDP probes from traceroute are being lost or dropped at the 11th probe. I was therefore keen to investigate whether this behaviour would continue if I used a box with a different OS. It now seems I cannot pursue it using a Linux box--else I would have to mess with code and try to recompile traceroute.